# How to represent voxel volume in VTK file format?

Tags: file-format, vtk, voxel, paraview

I have 3D binary array which represents a volume, where `a[x,y,z] = 0` indicates no object and `a[x,y,z] = 1` indicates the object region.

I want to save this as a VTK file and view it in [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/).  What is the simplest way to achieve this? Suggestions for other approaches are welcome.

I looked through the [VTK file format](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf), but I have not found direct way to achieve what I need, just via other structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Paraview accepts raw data http://paraview.org/Wiki/Data_formats#Raw_files.
So why not just write out your data in a triple for-loop to raw binary data?

How to open raw data file in Paraview (edit):

Example: *Fuel* from [Uni Tuebingen](http://www.gris.uni-tuebingen.de/edu/areas/scivis/volren/datasets/datasets.html)

1. open `.raw` file
2. properties: Data Scalar Type: `unsigned char`
   properties: Data Extend: `1<tab>64<tab>1<tab>64<tab>1<tab>64`
   properties: Apply
3. click on `Contour` (next to the calculator symbol)
   properties: Apply

Now you should see something. From here you can play around a bit.

In VTK itself (i.e. calling from C++) I remember there were some nice volume render algorithms available (ray casting, 2D textures, etc) but I could not find them in paraview right now. Edit: But Robert could (see comment).

Comment: Good idea! Thanks. I tried to load first example into ParaView from http://www.gris.uni-tuebingen.de/edu/areas/scivis/volren/datasets/datasets.html (Aneurism), but I was not able to obtain the same picture as on icon http://www.gris.uni-tuebingen.de/edu/areas/scivis/volren/datasets/images/aneurism.jpg. How to achieve such picture? I am new in ParaView.

Comment: I extended my answer to explain how to load the volume data from the webpage and create a contour. The nice pictures on the webpage might have been made with vtk directly, so no guarantee they are possible to obtain with Paraview

Comment: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2003-January/000078.html: a bit outdated (from 2003) but not a good sign

Comment: Tao, thanks a lot for so clear answer and comments! I can view my object! it works both for .raw and for .vtk as well. it seems I should learn ParaView, because it is not obvious how to use it from the beginning

Comment: ParaView does support volume rendering. Under the display tab change the representation to Volume. You can than adjust the Volume rendering algorithm under display->Volume mapper.

Comment: Unfortunately the Uni Tuebingen website is no longer available.